# How do you programmatically sign jar files in Java?

Tags: java, jar, digital-signature, jar-signing

Has anyone done this before? The only reference I have found on google has been: [https://web.archive.org/web/20150423130641/http://www.onjava.com/2001/04/12/signing_jar.html](http://onjava.com/onjava/2001/04/12/signing_jar.html) which still uses sun.* classes that will cause issues...

Found this as well, but does not work with java16: https://svn.cs.cf.ac.uk/projects/whip/trunk/whip-core/src/main/java/org/whipplugin/data/bundle/JarSigner15.java

Comment: you could just call the jar signer process from within java. best using ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 5):

To address a sudden change of security restrictions in WebStart applications in Java 7u45 we have created a [simple signed jar file generator](https://gist.github.com/mmm444/7086899). It uses Guava 15 and Bouncy Castle bcpkix module. It should run on Java 6 & 7. It is suitable for small files only. Use it for any purpose you want.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that the `sun.security.tools.JarSigner` class was written to be used as a command-line utility and wasn't designed to be called from Java code. As a result, the error handling is pretty abrupt: the code will simply print an error message to standard out and then call `System.exit()` [1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/tools/JarSigner.java).

This means that if you call the class from within your Java code and an error occurs when you try to sign a jar, the JVM running your code will simply stop. This may be fine depending on your situation, but if your code is long running or acting as a service, it's not so good.

It's therefore better to call the jarsigner tool using the ProcessBuilder as per clamp's comment. You can then call `waitFor()` on the resulting Process object and check `exitValue()` to see if the command was successful. `getInputStream()` will let you read any error messages that were written to standard out if the operation fails.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to do this with JDK 9 and beyond:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
import java.security.*;
import jdk.security.jarsigner.*;

char[] password = ...;
String keyStorePath = ...;
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(new File(keyStorePath), password);
KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam =
   new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password);

KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)
   ks.getEntry("codecheck", protParam);

JarSigner signer = new JarSigner.Builder(pkEntry)
   .build();
String inputFile = ...;
String outputFile = ...;
try (ZipFile in = new ZipFile(inputFile);
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
   signer.sign(in, out);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the tools.jar file is the class sun.security.tools.JarSigner which has a static run(ava.lang.String[] strings) method that takes the same parameters as the jarsigner executable does.

So you can call something like:

```
sun.security.tools.JarSigner.run(new String[] {
    "-keystore", keystoreFile.getAbsolutePath(),
    "-storepass", keystorePassword,
    outFile.getAbsolutePath(),
    keystoreAlias 
});
```

You need to make sure tools.jar is in your classpath for compiling and execution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [SingJar Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html) (which apparently calls the command line tool underneath). It should be possible to call that programmatically.

Comment: @wuntee: I suspect that the Ant taks would do that if it were easily possible.