# jnlp file containing a set of signed and unsigned jars

Tags: java, security, jnlp, signed, mixed-code

I have a set of jars that I build and signed on the build machine and deploy to our servers. 
There is one other jar that is created dynamically on the server itself and I have no way of signing it. All of the jars are downloaded together as stated in the jnlp file.

When I run the application, I get a notice from the browser informing of this signed and unsigned mix and asks to allow or deny?

Is there anything I can do to eliminate the browsers notice? in my jnlp?

Thoughts?

Comment: 1) Do you? 2) Yes. 3) No. 4) Ask 1 question, instead of 4.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to eliminate the browsers notice?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688676/how-do-you-programmatically-sign-jar-files-in-java

Comment: the issue is not the process of signing it on the fly, it is of signing it on the running server and not having the certificates on the server.